# Java: String and Character Comparison

Tags: java, string, char, comparison

I'm writing a program that keeps track of team names and how many times that team has won a game based on user input. I need to allow for the user to input a String (for the team name) and an x to exit. I need to be able to compare a string and a character in a while loop (while (String != x)). So far I've tried:

```
char exitProgram = 'x';
String x = Character.toString(exitProgram);
while (winningTeam != x)
```

as well as:

```
while (winningTeam.charAt(0) != 'x')
```

However, neither of these result in a while loop that exits when x is entered. I'm not sure if it's a problem with trying to turn a char into a String or if I'm doing something else wrong but I'm pretty sure it's something I'm not understanding with the comparison. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: This has been marked as a duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

and while they're similar, I believe my question differs in needing to know how to compare a character to a string (i.e finding the correct character to string conversion) rather than just comparing two strings.

Comment: Since `String` is an Object, it's best to use the included `equals()` method. eg `myString.equals("test")`

Comment: Please see [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/1553851) and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Why is exitProgram a Char? Does it have to be or can it be a string?

Comment: Your 2nd comparison is fine. You need to provide more code. Please read about creating a [mcve].

Comment: Eclipse recognizes 'x' as a char, I tried to cast exitProgram as a string and the program wouldn't compile. Thank you for the idea, though. As for using .equals(), I'm continuing to have the same problem. Luckily I can talk to my TA tonight during office hours. Thanks you guys for the recommendations!

Comment: With your first example, you can use `while (!x.equals(winningTeam)) {...}` (per *How do I compare strings in Java?*).